# Need to check if link exists for any given SharePoint URL using RESTAPI or CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using SharePoint 2013 Online. The requirement is, for any given SP Online URL I should be able to verify if it is broken or not using client side code/script not server side code.

Please help me on this if any one have done this before.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: URL can be any object? list url, site url, permission group etc.?

Comment: URL will be simply a string , that can be a sub site url, list url, group url, any page url, document url etc. URL can point to any resource within the SP site.